# How to create data disks for azure virtual machines?

Tags: json, powershell, azure, msdn

I have added multiple data disks to virtual machines while creating virtual machines using the following json template.

```
"variables": {  
"diskArray": [  
{  
"name": "datadisk1",
"lun": 0,   
"vhd": {  
"uri": "[concat('http://', variables('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/','datadisk1.vhd')]"  
        },  
        "createOption": "Empty",    
        "caching": "ReadWrite",    
        "diskSizeGB": 300    
      },    
      {    
        "name": "datadisk2",
        "lun": 1,
        "vhd": {
          "uri": "[concat('http://', variables('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/', 'datadisk2.vhd')]"    
        },  
        "createOption": "Empty",    
        "caching": "ReadWrite",    
        "diskSizeGB": 200  
      },  
      {   
        "name": "datadisk3",  
        "lun": 2,  
        "vhd": {  
          "uri": "[concat('http://', variables('storageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/', 'datadisk3.vhd')]"  
        },  
        "createOption": "Empty",  
        "caching": "ReadWrite",  
        "diskSizeGB": 100  
      }  
]    
  },    
.....    
.....   
"resources": [  
    {  
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",  
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",  
      "name": "[concat(parameters('VmPrefix'), copyindex(1))]",  
      "copy": {  
        "name": "Datanode",  
        "count": "[variables('vmcount')]"  
      },  
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",  
      "properties": {  
         ......  
         ......  
        "storageProfile": {  
          "imageReference": {  
            ........  
          },  
          "dataDisks":   "[take(variables('diskArray'),parameters('numDataDisks'))]",  
          "osDisk": {  
            .......  
          }  
        }  
    }  
}  
]
```

This code works fine while creating single virtual machine, but while creating multiple virtual machines, machines failed to create. This is because vhd created for datadisks for first machine is same as other machines.

Is there a way to create a vhd with different name?
Tried passing copy index, but does not works.

Answer (score 2):

Sure there is, I will paste a link to a template doing that and explain how it works. Here's the [link](https://github.com/4c74356b41/armotron/blob/master/ml-vm-ml-dd.json).

So in order to do that, you have to add copyindex (or something like that) into the disk name, one of the way to do that, is use a nested template that will return an object with disks in it, and while calling the template you can use copyindex as a parameter for it.

[This is](https://github.com/4c74356b41/armotron/blob/master/ml-vm-ml-dd.json#L180-L206) where you create nested deployment to create disks object.
And [here](https://github.com/4c74356b41/armotron/blob/master/ml-vm-ml-dd.json#L161) you use the output to create disks.

Comment: While running the above sample json i got the following error:      New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:13
+ $response = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCommand

Comment: but virtual machines are created properly with data disks.

Comment: well, I'm not sure what you are doing wrong, for me this works fine, if this does what you are asking for, accept this as an answer ;) I've just tested this deployment and it worked fine. `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name test -ResourceGroupName zxc -TemplateUri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/4c74356b41/armotron/master/ml-vm-ml-dd.json`

Comment: Updated Azure power-shell modules to latest version 3.6.0 fixed my problem, and I have already marked this as answer as Virtual machines were created with data disks successfully.